# Does intelliJ have a String Substitution capabilities?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, intellij-idea

Ihave used [String Substitution Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-string_substitution.htm) in Eclipse to set properties that would otherwise be pulled in by Maven.

I am now developing in IntelliJ, and looking for similar capability, so I can substitute string params when running tests locally from IntelliJ.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I'd consider doing data-driven tests and removing any IDE dependencies.

Comment: this isn't an option at the moment, thanks for the response though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have such feature. There is `Settings` | `Path Variables`, but it's effective only for the file system paths and works transparently, without explicitly specifying the variables in the dialog.

Note that several Run/Debug configuration types have an option to specify custom environment variables which may be of some help.